# UIView.addSubView() not working within a closure within a closure

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, uiview

Essentially I'm trying to creating a function that sets up multiple notifications and while it does this, I want it to display a loading/progress bar in an alert view and update this while it sets up the notifications.

The problem is that the UI is not updating when I'm adding the progress view to the alert view as a subview, until the processing is complete.

Usually I fix this kind of problem with 'DispatchQueue.main.async'. But this doesn't seem to make a difference.

Below is the code. In the 'PresentLoadingView' function, the processing in the 'SetUpNotifications' function that is passed as the 'viewPresented' closure function finishes before the UI actually shows that the 'progressView' is added to the 'loadingView'.

I'm pretty sure this is a threading issue as it doesn't seem to reach the main UI thread when using 'DispatchQueue.main.async', possibly something to do with it having an @escaping parameter? Or just the fact that it is a closure within a closure?

```
var centre: UNUserNotificationCenter?

func AttemptToSetUpNotifications() {
    centre = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    centre!.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge], completionHandler: SetUpNotificationsChecks)
}

func SetUpNotificationsChecks(granted: Bool, error: Error?) {

    if error != nil {
        return
    }

    if !granted {
        return
    }

    PresentLoadingView(viewPresented: SetUpNotifications)
}

var loadingView: UIAlertController?

func PresentLoadingView(viewPresented: @escaping ((UIProgressView)-> Void)) {

    loadingView = UIAlertController(title: "Setup Notifications", message: "Setting up notifications, please wait...", preferredStyle: .alert)

    self.present(loadingView!, animated: true, completion: {
        //  Add your progressbar after alert is shown
        let margin:CGFloat = 8.0
        let rect = CGRect(x:margin, y:72.0, width:self.loadingView!.view.frame.width - margin * 2.0 , height:2.0)
        let progressView = UIProgressView(frame: rect)
        progressView.progress = 0.0
        progressView.tintColor = Common.CommonTintColor

        self.loadingView!.view.addSubview(progressView)

//            DispatchQueue.main.async {
//                self.loadingView!.view.addSubview(progressView)
//            }

        viewPresented(progressView)
    })
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, sorry if the problem is my lack of concurrency knowledge, and if you need anymore info, please ask.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it not getting added, or is the `frame` just not set yet and you're ending up with a zero width subview? I'd suggest taking a look in "view debugger". You can eliminate that problem by using constraints instead of trying to manually set the frame.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the reply. I did not know view debugger existed - that is a very cool way to view the app so thanks for teaching me that. Anyway, when I put a breakpoint on the 'viewPresented(progressView)' line, the view debugger shows me that the UIProgressView has been added with the correct width, however the UIImageView within the UIProgressView is blank rather than grey (Which it is when the UIProgressView eventually appears after the processing). So maybe the UIProgressView isn't being instantiated properly?

Comment: Then your problem is much different then described. If you can see it then it was added as a subview. Also note its displaying 0%. That might be why it appears blank.

Comment: @AndrewMcKinley Yeah I guess it is a bit different now I found out a different way to debug it. I know for sure that the problem isn't that the UIProgressView is at 0%. Because it does appear after the processing, even when the progress is set to 0%. The issue seems to be that the UIProgressView is not rendered/instantiated completely.

Comment: @Rob If you can think of an alternative way to approach this requirement, then I don't mind trying that instead

Comment: I'm gathering that the problem is nothing to do with closures, no? If so, that portion of your question should be excised. I'd suggest creating the [simplest possible example that manifests the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that (a) you can confirm it has nothing to do with closures; and (b) so we have a small reproducible example of the problem. When you reference a bunch of unrelated stuff (closures, your `Common` structure, etc.), it can be hard to figure out whether the problem is the code in the question, or something else...

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the response. I have taken your advice and have created a much simpler example of the issue I am having [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46258649/how-do-i-make-subview-appear-in-ui-immediately-after-adding-it). Apologies for this question being obtuse in the first place.