# How do I make subview appear in UI immediately after adding it?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

Essentially I want a label to appear as a subview when I add it and not wait until the current thread has finished what it is doing. In the below example, the label appears in the UI of the app at the same time 'Awake' is printed. Do you know how I can get the subview to appear in the UI before the thread sleeps?

```
@IBAction func ButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    let label = UILabel(frame: self.view.bounds)
    label.text = "Label Text"
    self.view.addSubview(label) // I want this to appear on the UI before...
    sleep(3)
    print("Awake") // ... this is printed

}
```

And enclosing the addSubView() line within DispatchQueue.main.async {} doesn't fix the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Dispatch the other task onto a background queue so that you don't block the main queue

Comment: Instead of posting fake code that doesn't reproduce your issue, update your question with real code.

Comment: @rmaddy This isn't fake code, this is the exact code I am running.

Comment: Really? You stated: *"In my actual code, I'm adding a progress view, not a label. And I am doing some processing for a few seconds instead of using sleep()."* So clearly this isn't your actual code and you are not really calling `sleep`. So again, post your actual code if you want help fixing your actual code.

Comment: @rmaddy Ah yeah, sorry I can see how that could be confusing. I meant in my original code before I tried to create the simplest possible example that manifests the problem. Sorry for needlessly mentioning what was in my original code and poorly wording it. I'll edit it out.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that your question contains vastly oversimplified code. It does not actually represent your real issue. Post your actual code causing your issue. That's the only way people can help you solve your actual issue. Because the solution to the code in your question is to simply remove the use of `sleep`. And obviously that solution doesn't help solve your real problem.

Comment: With the understanding that the sleep is a proxy for an intensive task (which is the code you should have shown, not the full code but the function invocation with a comment that it takes several seconds to run) , the UI update needs to be performed by the main queue, but your `sleep` is blocking the main queue, so the update doesn't occur until the sleep is over. Dispatching async doesn't help, since the dispatched block also won't execute until the main queue is free to do so. You need to dispatch your `sleep` onto another queue so that the main queue isn't blocked.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks a lot! That makes total sense. I figured out how to do that in swift, and it works. So thank you!

Comment: @rmaddy Actually, solving this simple problem (Which Paulw11 did) solves my actual problem. I designed this question in such a way so that answering it, solves my actual problem. It's solved now, so no worries.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Paulw11, I figured out that I need to do the processing on a background thread. Simple solution in swift:

```
@IBAction func ButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    let label = UILabel(frame: self.view.bounds)
    label.text = "Label Text"
    self.view.addSubview(label) // I want this to appear on the UI before...

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        sleep(3)
        print("Awake") // ... this is printed
    }

}
```